# How to you load apache in 64 bit mode

Tags: apache-2.2, 64-bit

The following command will load Apache from 64 to 32 bit (Mac OS):

```
sudo arch -i386 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

What is the command if I want then to switch back to 64 bit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the `arch` command to specify an architecture:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/httpd
```

(This assumes that you've killed off the previously running instance of httpd).